# Create new Object instead of clone while creating defensive copy

Tags: java

It is being said in [effective java](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/effectivejava-136174.html) in item:Make defensive copies when needed, that **do not use the clone method to make a defensive copy of a parameter whose type is subclassable by untrusted parties**.

I am not able to understand what does this actually mean.

Comment: You don't know what `clone()` might do if a third party sub-classes your class. For most projects, this would be worrying about something which is unlikely to ever be a problem, however for the JDK this is the sort of thing they have to be concerned about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the concern that the book is highlighting in that section.

```
 public MyOtherClass implements Cloneable {
     public Object clone() {
         super.clone();
     }
 }

 public MyOtherClass {
     private MyClass m;

     public MyOtherClass(MyClass m) {
         this.m = m.clone();  // Defensive copy.
     }
 }

 public SneakyClass extends MyClass {
     public clone() {
         return this;         // !!!!!!
     }
 }
```

By passing an instance of `SneakyClass` to the `MyOtherClass` constructor, someone can *defeat* the defensive copy that the constructor is trying to do.  As you can see, the override for `clone()` *does not* return a copy of the target object.

(The solution in this case if to declare `MyClass` as `final` or declare `MyClass.clone()` as `final`.)

Answer (score 2):

The item you are talking about is describing how to properly implement an immutable class.

The full paragraph says:

> Note also that we did not use Date's clone method to make the defensive copies. Because Date is nonfinal, the clone method is not guaranteed to return an object whose class is java.util.Date; it could return an instance of an untrusted subclass specifically designed for malicious mischief. Such a subclass could, for example, record a reference to each instance in a private static list at the time of its creation and allow the attacker access to this list. This would give the attacker free reign over all instances. To prevent this sort of attack, **do not use the clone method to make a defensive copy of a parameter whose type is subclassable by untrusted parties**.

To show what the rest of the paragraph is describing, imagine a `clone` method that did this:

```
public class Foo implements Cloneable {
    private int bar;
    private static List<Foo> secretList = new ArrayList<>();

    public Foo(int bar) { this.bar = bar; }

    @Override
    public Foo clone() {
        Foo copy = new Foo(this.bar);
        secretList.add(copy); // this is the line of concern
        return copy;
    }
}
```

Now the `Foo` class still has access to the instance it created, meaning it could maliciously modify the instance even if it were to be a member of an immutable class.

Comment: long story short *cloned object always modifies itself according to change in original object which is a bad idea*